# SystemJS Builder + Babel issue

Tags: javascript, babeljs, systemjs

I'm trying out SystemJS and getting an issue when trying to use the builder alongside babel.

It's a simple ES2015 project, so won't bore you with the details of that, but my bundle setup looks like the below.

config.js:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'babel',
    paths: {
        'babel': './node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/browser.js'
    }
});
```

builder.js:

```
var path = require("path");
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

var builder = new Builder('.', 'config.js');

builder
    .buildStatic('./src/app.js', './dist/index.js')
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Build complete');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Build error');
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I'm getting the following error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined` on the `browser.js` file from babel. Prior to adding the babel path, I was getting an error that SystemJS was trying to locate `babel.js` relative to my source directory.

I'm obviously missing something simple here, but the docs aren't exactly straight forward, and seem to be a bit outdated with regards to babel. Do I need to run babel on the files prior to bundling with SystemJS so that require is available or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not positive on this because I use jspm so I didn't have to set this up manually, but it looks like the correct main file for babel-core is `./node_modules/babel-core/browser.js` which has "format global"; instead of "format cjs"; which would explain your error.